# oracle agile plm file manager issue while uploading

Tags: java, axis, oracle-agile-plm

Hi i am using oracle plm and got error while uploading documents

Exception :Error code : 60086
Error message : Call APIException.getRootCause() for details.
Root Cause exception : com.agile.webfs.components.common.RepositoryException: The preferred file server : http://ONEPART2.enconnect.com:8080/Filemgr/services/FileServer for current user is down. Please contact the system administrator.

Comment: error:    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.configureEngine(FileProvider.java:179)
 at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.init(AxisEngine.java:172)
 at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.<init>(AxisEngine.java:156)
 at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.<init>(AxisClient.java:52)
 at org.apache.axis.client.Service.getAxisClient(Service.java:104)
 at org.apache.axis.client.Service.<init>(Service.java:113)
 at com.agile.webfs.components.fileserver.client.FileServerWSServiceLocator.<init>(FileServerWSServiceLocator.java:10)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.axis.utils.XMLUtils.initSAXFactory(XMLUtils.java:219)
 at org.apache.axis.utils.XMLUtils.<clinit>(XMLUtils.java:107)

Comment: You have to add your above comments as a part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are uploading documents via webclient- then please check if your filemanager is up and running. Or Simply restart the filemanager services and try uploading the document.

If this error occurred when using SDK to upload a document- then there are different troubleshooting approach.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by incompatible version of axis.jar included in the PX deployment archive lib folder. A special version of axis.jar is included in the application server's Java runtime environment CLASSPATH. Adding the axis.jar to the PX deployment archive's lib folder creates a conflict and may cause the PX deployment to fail.

Solution: Remove the axis.jar form the PX deployment archive lib folder. It is not needed for an internal custom action PX, which runs in the server's Java runtime.

For URL PX, or Agile API based clients, the axis.jar should be included in the CLASSPATH along with these other Axis dependent jar file:

```
jaxrpc.jar
saaj.jar
commons-discovery.jar
commons-logging.jar
wsdl4j.jar or orawsdl.jar
xercesImpl.jar
mail.jar
activation.jar
```

If one or more of the above axis dependent jar file(s) is missing but the axis.jar is in the the client side CLASSPATH, the attachment operations from SDK will not work.